# Element position to stay in the same place when scrolling horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a Google first page copy and i have a problem with the footer.
My copy footer look like this:[image]

And i'm trying to achieve this:
[image]

That part with privacy, terms and settings, i want to make it stay in the same position

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Google</title>
    <!-- font awesome -->
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8370b7a799.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <a href="#">Gmail</a>
      <a href="#">Images</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-buromobelexperte fa-lg"></i></a>
      <a href="#" id="account-nav-link">S</a>
    </nav>
    <main class="main-google">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="img-div">
          <img src="google.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="search-box">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          <input type="text" />
          <i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="search-buttons">
          <button class="changed-button">Google Search</button>
          <button class="changed-button">I'm Felling Lucky</button>
        </div>
        <div class="lang-div">
          <span>Google offered in:</span>
          <a href="#">Romana</a>
          <a href="#">magyar</a>
          <a href="#">Deutsch</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
      <div>
        <p class="location">Romania</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-link-bar">
        <a href="#">Advertising</a>
        <a href="#">Business</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">How Search works</a>
        <span class="footer-links-right">
          <a href="#">Privacy</a>
          <a href="#">Terms</a>
          <a href="#">Settings</a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

is it better to move that span outside the footer?

CSS

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer div {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.location {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.footer div a {
  margin-left: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5f6368;
}

.footer div a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5f6368;
}

.footer-links-right {
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.footer span a {
  margin-right: 27px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

And for the text decoration, i've tried to modify text-decoration-thickness but it doesn't work so i've used border bottom, but is there another posibility for me to use tect-decoration?

Comment: So you are programming all of this with Paint only? Or you also have some HTML?

Comment: haha sry, i'm editing right now

Answer (score 0):

for the footer add a fixed minimum width, not a percentage.

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 750px; /* footer doesn't shrink less than 750px */
}
```

rather you should add it to the container of the whole page for your desired situation.

```css
body {
    width: 100vw; /* maintain width of 100 view width(users viewpoint)** */
    min-width: 750px; /* body doesn't shrink less than 750px */
}
```

** Relative Lengths => https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: i think that's not the solution for my problem. I'm not concern about the shrinking, i'm just trying to achieve the same effect as the google page, like when i'm shrinking the page horizontally, the right part of the footer to stay still (outside of the view )